# Additional request are sending after first request upload file using xhr ajax with formData

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc, file-upload

I have spend many hours of trying simulate this error on localhost, but without success.This error happend sometime on live version of web. From live version of web is send error email.

Here is Error

```
The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'isJsonResponse' of non-nullable type 'System.Boolean' for method 'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult UploadFileDocument(Model, Boolean)' in Controller'. An optional parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional parameter.
```

Here is javascript:

```
 $('#uploadFile').click(function () {            

        var input = $('#file')[0];

        if (input.files.length == 0) return;

        $(".titleRed", $('#files')).remove();

        var dObject = new Object();
        dObject.TypeID = $('#types').val();
        dObject.FileName = input.files[0].name;
        dObject.File = input.files[0];
        dObject.ID = '@HttpUtility.JavaScriptStringEncode(Model.ID)';

        var formData = new FormData();
        for (var key in dObject) {
            formData.append(key, dObject[key]);
        }

        formData.append('isJsonResponse', false);
        uploadFiles(formData, function (result) {

            if (typeof result == 'object') {
                console.log(result.msg);
            } else {
                $('#files').append(result);
                $('#fileAlert').remove();
            }



        });
            document.getElementById('file').value = '';
            $('#types').val('1');

        return false;
    });
```

Function uploadFile:

```
function uploadFiles(formData, updateCallback,progressCallback,startCallback,errorCallback) {

    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('POST', _uploadFilesURL);


    //listner on progress (%) for progress bar
    xhr.upload.addEventListener("progress", function (evt) {
        if (evt.lengthComputable) {
            if (typeof progressCallback != "undefined") {

                //count %
                var percentComplete = evt.loaded / evt.total;
                percentComplete = parseInt(percentComplete * 100);
                debugLog(percentComplete);
                progressCallback(percentComplete, this.progressId);
            }
        }
    }, false);

    // when downloading start create unique ID for progress bar
    xhr.upload.addEventListener("loadstart", function (e) {
        if (typeof startCallback != "undefined") {
            // generating uniqe ID (GUID)
            this.progressId = 'xxxxxxxx-xxxx-4xxx-yxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx'.replace(/[xy]/g, function (c) { var r = Math.random() * 16 | 0, v = c == 'x' ? r : r & 0x3 | 0x8; return v.toString(16); });
            startCallback(this.progressId);
        }
    });

    //callback on final result of request
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
            var data = null;

            //if crash JSON.Parse then is possible that result is pure text(partialView)
            try {
                data = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);                    

            } catch (e) {

            }
            if (data == null) {                  
                //supose it is pure text if json parse crash
                updateCallback(xhr.responseText);
            } else {
                updateCallback(data.result);
            }

        } else if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status != 200) {
            if (typeof errorCallback != "undefined") {
                errorCallback(xhr);
            }
        }
    }

    xhr.send(formData);
```

}

Here is Asp net MVC method code:

```
     [HttpPost]
public ActionResult UploadFile(Model mode, bool isJsonResponse)
    {
```

Model :

```
 public class Model
{      
    public string FileName { get; set; }      
    public int TypeID { get; set; }
    public int? ModelID { get; set; }

    public HttpPostedFileBase File { get; set; }
    public int ID { get; set; }

}
```

The file is normaly uploaded. But after that, sometimes is send another request but without fileBody and other parametrs like is isJsonResponse. The post only contains TypeID and FileName.

The error is comming from IE,FF,Chrome

Have somebody experience with this? Or something similiar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK , so after another testing with application clumsy, i finally simulate the behaviour. I release that happend when internet connection is unstable.